# How to assign array variable using explode value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my sample.json file

```
  "general": {
    "option_name" : "option_name",
    "filter_name" : "filter name"
}
```

and I want to update the value using key

```
$string = "general.filter_name";

$updateContent = "new filtername";

$langArray = explode('.',$string);

print_r($langArray);

/*Array
(
[0] => general
[1] => filter_name
) */


$file='assets/sample.json';

$jsonString = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

**$data['general']['filter_name'] = $updateContent; **


$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents($file, $newJsonString);
```

Here I want to assign Array

```
 [0] => general
 [1] => filter_name
```

should be

```
$data['general']['filter_name']
```

How to define array like this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using references:

```
$json = file_get_contents('assets/sample.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);

$path = "general.filter_name";
$path = explode('.', $path);

$ref = &$json;

foreach ($path as $key) {
    $ref = &$ref[$key];
}

$ref = "new filtername";
unset($ref);
```

How it works:

1. Create a reference for your array: `$ref = &$json;`
2. Iterate through `$path` items to get value of `$json['general']['filter_name']`:

   1. On the first iteration `$ref` will be reference to `$json['general']`
   2. On the second iteration `$ref` will be reference to `$json['general']['filter_name']` - that's exactly what we want
3. When assign `$ref = "new filtername";` you're assigning `$json['general']['filter_name'] = "new filtername";`
4. Don't forget to remove reference `unset($ref);`, without doing it there is possibility to change `$ref` and thus to change `$json['general']['filter_name']`